# Getting empty object back in Python using Google Cloud Vision library

Tags: python, request, google-cloud-vision

I'm currently working on a discord bot that allows for some commands that make API calls to the google-cloud libraries such as language and vision. However, I'm having no errors, but sometimes my images don't get labeled. I'm using the Google Cloud Vision library for Python3.7.

This commands returns nothing except for an empty list.
`analyseimg("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/294469159004143617/645054741042167838/1.png")`

The same image is now uploaded to imgur and suddenly returns a full list of labels.
`analyseimg("https://i.imgur.com/crluCYG.png")`

```
from google.cloud import vision


def analyseimg(url):
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient.from_service_account_json('cred.json')
    image = vision.types.Image()
    image.source.image_uri = url
    response = client.label_detection(image=image)
    labels = response.label_annotations
    print('Labels:')
    for label in labels:
        print(label.description, label.score)
    return labels
```

Is there something specific that I'm looking over?

EDIT: I edited my code, and now it is working, however I still don't know why.

```
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
import requests
import io


def analyseimg(url):
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient.from_service_account_json('cred.json')
    img = requests.get(url).content
    image = types.Image(content=img)
    response = client.label_detection(image=image)
    labels = response.label_annotations
    print('Labels:')
    for label in labels:
        print(label.description, label.score)
    return labels
```

Comment: Are there any errors logged in the Stackdriver logs when you run your app?  I downloaded both images from the links above and used https://cloud.google.com/vision/ to test them and they both worked.   I'm wondering if there is something in the returned HTTP headers that might be confusing something.  The two images appear to have distinct sizes ... one is 611837 while the other is 611674 ...

Comment: @Kolban I've made slight edit to my code, and now it is working. I don't know if I am able to see the returned HTTPS headers because I am using a Python library for it. And with the sizes, I think imgur strips some data from the image.